# Lock table cells to their default size regardless of content

Tags: html, css, html-table, resize, css-tables

If I have

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and

```
table
    { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Each cell takes up an equal quarter of the table, and the table stretches to fit the window.

How can I prevent these table cells from resizing themselves to fit the content within the cells (while still fitting the table's container)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try `table-layout:fixed;` - this sets the layout to a certain fixed size (specified in CSS) and ignores the content of the cells, so the width of the cell never changes. I'm not sure if this affects vertical layout or not.

[More info on w3schools](http://w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp).

Comment: You're right -- it works on horizontal widths but not vertical.  I feel like CSS is useless for even the simplest of things.  I'm just trying to make a calendar!

Comment: @RomanGaufman I think that [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17429778/49942) works for vertical as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `position: absolute` on the content of each table cell: because if you do then the size of the content doesn't affect the size of the cell.

To do this, you must then also position the table cells (so that absolute positioning of the content is relative to the table cell) -- [and/or, to support Firefox, position an extra div within the table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements) since Firefox doesn't let you apply position to the cells themselves.

For example, I'm using this HTML:

```
<td><div class="bigimg"><img src="...."/></div></td>
```

Together with the following CSS, so that the size of the image doesn't affect the size of the cell which contains it:

```
div.bigimg
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
div.bigimg > img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I set the `height` and `width` of `div.bigimg` to `100%` to match the size of the `td` which contains it, because I'm using JavaScript to resize the images at run time to fit their containers, which are the `div.bigimg`.

---

Here's another example, using text instead of images -- same principle though, i.e. position: absolute inside position: relative inside each cell and the cells don't fit the content.

[image]

Comment: Is there some explanation as to WHY this would be required? a 3x3 table seems to resize even though the image already fits within the table cell!

Comment: @ericslaw I don't understand your comment/question. Maybe you could post it as a new question.

Comment: @PhilipRego I don't see why -- if the cell's content is `position: absolute` then it's no longer really content, is it, i.e. no longer positioned as a child of the cell. Are you sure your cell content is 'position:absolute` (see e.g. the HTML and CSS in my answer)?

Comment: @PhilipRego Wrap each p inside a div; make the div position relative, and make the p position absolute. The table will then layout as if there's nothing inside each cell (i.e. cells will be too small for the content unless you resize them), the apparently-empty div will be positioned in each cell, and the paragraphs will be positioned on (but won't affect the size of) each div.

Comment: @PhilipRego I added a corrected version of your example to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to do this without fixed table layout.
The cell's css:

```
.dataCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2px 15px 2px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to pick a single cell to chew up all the space and set that to 100% height and width:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hi There.</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Here is some text.</td>
        <td class="space-hog"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and some CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.space-hog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/W8uT8/). You need to be careful to avoid unpleasant line wrapping when `.space-hog` does its thing, hence the `white-space: nowrap`. If you put the `.space-hog` in the last row then you can avoid pushing the interesting parts down.

Comment: I'm not trying to get one cell to take up all the space -- I want ever cell to be equal in width and height regardless of content.

Comment: Okay, it wasn't clear to me. I don't think there is a way to say "make all these things the same size" in CSS, you have to say "make all these things Wpx wide and Hpx tall" and compute the dimensions yourself on the server or in JavaScript. Maybe supply more context in the question and someone might come up with a whole new approach that avoids table sizing kludges entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can also lock the cells to a percentage, in order to maintain responsiveness, eg:

```
  td:first-child, th:first-child {
    width: 20%;
  }
  // assuming you have 8 remaining columns (20 + 10*8 = 100%)
  td:not(:first-child), th:not(:first-child) {
    width: 10%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`td{ width:50%; }` will work until the table gets small enough.

Comment: What if I don't know the number of rows or columns in advance?  I've been using Javascript to give each cell a percentage width and height but can no longer do this.

Comment: I can't think of a pure HTML/CSS solution, you will probably need Javascript. You could try playing with the CSS overflow property.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of using `overflow:hidden;` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers were working for me. I found a hack that works for me:

```
td {
  max-width: 0;
}
```

This is almost definitely wrong, but I'm desperate, so into the codebase it goes.

Honestly just use CSS grid. This crap is stupid.

Answer (score -2):

Add `table-layout:fixed;` to the table's styling.

If you notice this helps fix the width but not the height, this is because there might still exist some sort of padding within each td cell. Add `padding:0px;` to the td's styling.