# Differences with CSS positioning between IE9 and Opera, and Firefox and Opera

Tags: css, firefox, position, internet-explorer-9, absolute

I have a problem with a site I am doing some maintanence on, the latest test version can be found here http://www.smithandgeorg.com.au/new/ If viewed in IE7-9 or Opera this page displays as intended, however in Firefox and Safari the menu is positioned so that it is against the left side of the screen (it's best seen rather than described).

The problem seems to stem from my use of positioning. The `#content` element is positioned `position:relative; top:0px; left:0px` so that when the `#menu` element (which is nested inside) is positioned `position:absolute; left:0px` it will be pushed right up against the left side of the `#content` element, as happens correctly in IE9 and Opera. However Firefox and Safari seem to ignore the fact that `#content` is positioned relatively and just push `#menu` up to the left side of the screen.

I tried to reproduce the problem in the simple page below, but everything worked as expected.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="border:1px solid red; width:100px; height:100px; position:relative; left:0px">
            <div style="border:1px solid black; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:60px; left:20px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox usually ignores `position:relative` on table elements, but this can be fixed by adding `display:block` to `#content`:

```
#content {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
display:block;
}
```

[SO question/answer about position:relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)