# position relative in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

Here is an example: full-width menu as a table and ul-s as dropdown menus. 
http://cssdesk.com/dW7WS

Works fine in ie and opera, but in firefox dropdown uls streched on whole screen!

Any help?

Comment: *full-width menu as a **table*** - First mistake.

Comment: No menus appear at all for me in IE9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`position: relative` does not work on table cells (`<td>` or `display: table-cell`).

From the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

So, Firefox is doing nothing wrong, although I do wish it would copy other browsers and make this work.

To make this work, you need to add a wrapper `div` inside each `td` (and adjust your CSS selectors):

```
<table id="mainmenu">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <a href="#">..</a>
                <ul>
                    ..
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>

        ..
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, thirtydot - you answer is most helpful. can you tell me, what style must be applyed to that container div?

Comment: You're welcome. You should move the `#mainmenu td` stuff to `#mainmenu td > div`. You should also change `#mainmenu td:hover > ul` to `#mainmenu td:hover > div > ul`. I've done it here for only the first one: http://cssdesk.com/hmWSd. That's the idea, anyway.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jared Farrish said using tables for layout is bad practice and the problem here.

```
#mainmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is causing the li elements to display 100% of the screen. I would suggest you wrap the menu in a container div, there is absolutely no need for a table here you should put the menu in an unordered list something like: -

```
<ul>
   <li class="parent_node"> Menu Header 1
        <ul class="sub_node">
             <li> Sub item 1</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="parent_node"> Menu Header 2
        <ul class="sub_node">
             <li> Sub item 1</li>
        </ul>
   </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: i used table because i need full-width menu, with divs i can only make it with display:table-cell, wich is unsupported in ie6.

Comment: i must add, i need full-width menu with menu items _streched_ on whole width.