# pseudo-element inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table, pseudo-element

I wanted to insert a **pseudo-element** ::before in **table-row**.
To get it out of the flow I use absolute positioning.
But I get some unexpected results.

If I apply it to all the tr elements it works fine.
But in the second example *table.two* it doesn't work like that. I am not able to get the pseudo-element out of the flow.

The only difference is that I target a **subset**.

I have no special design in mind. I just wanted to style the table row with a bit more flexibility. *Maybe with some fancy box-shadow?*

```css
table {
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 300px;
    }
    td { width: 33%; }
    
    /*  lets go */
    tr {
     position: relative; /*  reference point for pseudo elements */
    }
    tr.two::before, table.two tr::before {
     content: "test";
     color: red; background: rgba(255,200,0,0.7);
     position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 5%; bottom: 5%; right: 5%;
        z-index: -1;
        box-shadow: -1em 0 0.2em 0 rgba(255,200,0,0.4), 1em 0 0.2em 0 rgba(255,200,0,0.4);

    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
     <tr class="two">
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table class="two">
      <tr>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what this is supposed to look like?

Comment: I added a few lines to the code and the question to further explain the issue. Thanks for the tipp.

Comment: This may help explain why this is not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501727/table-row-wont-contain-elements-with-positionabsolute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are positioning the pseudo elements relatively to the `tr` which leads to undefined behavior:

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position).

**Full credit to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502084/3400962 for finding this out.**

This means you can't get the desired result by adding and positioning the pseudo element relatively to the `tr`.

To achieve the effect you are after, you can add and relatively position multiple pseudo elements to the `td` instead. The pseudo selectors `first-child` and `last-child` can be used to ensure that the `box-shadow` only applies to the ends of the `tr`.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
td {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
}
tr.two td::before,
table.two tr td::before {
  background: rgba(255, 200, 0, 0.7);
  bottom: 5%;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: -1;
}
tr.two td:first-child::before,
table.two tr td:first-child::before {
  box-shadow: -1em 0 0.2em 0 rgba(255, 200, 0, 0.4);
  color: red;
  content: "test";
  left: 5%;
}
tr.two td:last-child::before,
table.two tr td:last-child::before {
  box-shadow: 1em 0 0.2em 0 rgba(255, 200, 0, 0.4);
  right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="two">
  <tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem isnt in targeting, but this happen when there are rows with this pseudo element only in whole table, dunno why O_o, but it has something to do with `tr` stretching and so

```css
table {
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 300px;
    }
    td {
     width: 33%; }
    
    /*  lets go */
    tr {
     position: relative; /*  reference point for pseudo elements */
    }
    table tr.two td, table.two tr td{
        width:25%;
    }
    tr.two::before, table.two tr::before {
     content: "test";
     color: red; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
     position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
     <tr class="two">
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table class="two">
      <tr>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```