# Absolute Positioning inside a table cell in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having some issues with absolute positioning inside a table cell in Internet Explorer (9 specifically, but I'm sure the issue exists in <9 as well). I'm trying to force a div inside a table cell to take up the whole cell. It was pretty easy in chrome/ff/safari using:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}

td {
    position: relative;
}
```

But for some reason, IE behaves completely differently. I can't get it to give the div a dynamic height based on the table cell at all. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/x7UP6/2/) an example to show what I'm talking about. It works how I need it to in chrome/ff/safari, but it's broken in IE. Is there any way to get it to work the same way in IE? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Firefox. Are you sure you checked it in Firefox? If so, which version? Also, read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629326/position-relative-in-firefox/7629567#7629567

Comment: Ah, you're right, it doesn't work in FF... It's unfortunate that `position: relative;` on td's isn't supported in the w3c specs. Is there a reason for that? Is there a workaround or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: I don't know why the behavior wasn't defined in the specs. There isn't a particularly easy way to solve your problem. Why are you using a `table` in the first place?

Comment: I need a grid of an indeterminate number of uniform tiles that take up all available space in its container... And tables seemed like the best way to do it without using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still interested in this; a simple solution will fix the issue on IE 10 (my current target).

You need to have a nested div to locate your absolute positioned element:

```
<td>
    <div>
        <a href="#">FULL HEIGHT</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

And then add some css, including the lil trick for IE:

```
td {
    position: relative;
    height: 1px; // IE FIx
}
td > div {
    height: 100%;
}
td > div a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    // Beauty only
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you instead of positioning your element to all directions, use only two of them and instead, use size for your div.

like:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

td {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: A good tip that I'll probably use, but this doesn't answer my question. Your example doesn't work in IE. :)

Comment: which has the significant drawback of not being able to use margins and paddings with pixelvalues.