# Positioning context on table-cell element in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

Usually, we can set a parent element to be the context for a child's `absolute` positioning, as follows:

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This all works fine, but when the parent has its `display` property set to `table-cell`, it doesn't work in Firefox. The positioning context for the child element will be the closest positioned ancestor above its parent.

Of note, this works *everywhere* else. Tested in IE8, IE9, Safari, Chrome & Opera.

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ5Vx/

Also, see [this fiddle with the parent's `display` set to `inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ5Vx/1/), which does work in Firefox.

---

So, is this a bug? If so, is there anyway to work around it?

Comment: You can't position elements within a normal `TD` so I'd assume the browser engine isn't going to let you do it with a `table-cell` either.

Comment: @DA - But this works *everywhere* else. Is that just a lucky bug by everyone else?

Comment: You're not the first person who wants to do this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900433/absolute-positioning-inside-a-table-cell-in-ie. Click through my links until you get to the Firefox bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `table-cell` is meant to be inside a `table`, so:

See this [working Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/RZ5Vx/2/)

```
div {
    display: table;      /* this line */
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Note:**
Since you don't have a `table` in there, set it.

You can see this [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table) for the **The display declaration**.

---

### EDITED

From the [W3C recommendation :: Tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html) it reads

> The computed values of properties 'position', 'float', 'margin-*', 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' on the table element are used on the table wrapper box and not the table box; all other values of non-inheritable properties are used on the table box and not the table wrapper box. (Where the table element's values are not used on the table and table wrapper boxes, the initial values are used instead.)

This is not a bug, is more like a **status-bydesign** thing! Please see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#model)!

---

### EDITED

To include the work around placed on the comment as requested on the question:

> So, <strike>is this a bug? If so,</strike> is there anyway to work around it?

**Possible *work around* are:**

Wrap the element with a `div` as `position:relative;`  [See Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/RZ5Vx/6/)

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Note:** most practical solution!

Wrap the inner elements with a `div` as `position:relative;`  [See Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/RZ5Vx/7/)

```
#innerWrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Note:** requires some definitions from the original element to be declared on the innerWrapper!

Comment: None of this answers the question. I specifically want the element to be displayed as `table-cell`. And nope. It does *not* have to be within a table, which doesn't even help out with this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ5Vx/3/

Comment: Go around the issue and set the relative position to the [table](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/RZ5Vx/4/) or wrap your table-cell [with a div](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/RZ5Vx/5/) set to position:relative.

Comment: I only provided the test case. In the real world, I need several adjacent element to fill up the available width, and then have something positioned inside them. I obviously can only do that on the `table-cell` element itself.

Comment: @Joseph Silber, edited the answer with official documentation on the subject. Sorry if this does not go according to your goal, but it is as it is.

Comment: @Joseph Silber, I can add that I've been frustrated with this issue in the past, and I've provided an answer fast enough due to previous reading to deal with the subject, having concluded that a `table-cell` is by definition relative to the parent `table` thus being necessary a wrapper to overcome this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks! I used `position: relative` on the child element, and it works flawlessly cross browser. I didn't even have to add a superfluous element; I was dealing with a horizontal navbar - which consists of a list of links - with `display: table-cell` on the `li`s. All I did was move `position: relative` from the `li`s to the child `a`s! It's such a simple solution, I'm ashamed I didn't think of it myself.