# absolute positioning on :before element on element with display: table-cell

Tags: css, css-position

I have a row of elements and I want to style them using display: table-cell; to make the text position vertically in the middle. Sometimes a row will have an active state where I need to add a horizontal bar on top of the active element. This bar needs to be at least one pixel removed from the row. I used the :before pseudo element for this and it works great in Chrome, but not in Firefox because of the display: table-cell;.

Is there any solution for this? Preferably one without javascript.

Works in Chrome, not in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/Danny_Joris/CYwUZ/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="col1">col1 col1 col1</div>
  <div class="col2">col2 col2 col2</div>
  <div class="col3">col3 col3 col3</div>    
</div>

#wrapper {
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper > div {
  width: 33%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 75px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.col2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  height: 5px;
  background: lightblue;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positioning context on table-cell element in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902743/positioning-context-on-table-cell-element-in-firefox)