# CSS absolute positioned object inside table-cell displayed object in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have big trouble with CSS positioning with absolute element inside `display:table-cell` object. All browsers render correctly except Firefox.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li rel="sl1">
        <span class="sltitle">Item 1</span>
        <span class="pointer"></span>
    </li>
    <li rel="sl2">
        <span class="sltitle">Item 2</span>
        <span class="pointer"></span>
    </li>
    <li rel="sl3">
        <span class="sltitle">Item 3</span>
        <span class="pointer"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
.slider {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.slider li  {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #1C1A1A;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider li span.pointer {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

**Here is the JSFIDDLE for that**: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/SN7zL/

Please open this link in Chrome and then in Firefox, you'll see the difference.
Do you know any proper way how to fix this issuer?

Comment: Is the issue the fact that Firefox includes scrollbars? Or the borders overlapping? (Both?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has issues with absolute positioning and `display:table-cell` - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256004/firefox-issue-with-displayabsolute-in-a-table-cell)

You need to wrap the element in a block element with relative positioning and then it will work:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SN7zL/4/)

Comment: This really fixes issuer with Firefox! Thanks @Pete

Answer (score 1):

May be it's problem grow from this problem - [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

And - [Positioning context on table-cell element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902743/positioning-context-on-table-cell-element-in-firefox)

Wrap the element with a div as position:relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/N6bUU/2/

```
.rel {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I found this solution, but when I wrap it in DIV with `position:relative` it loses parent element height.
I mean, this `.pointer` element should be 100% height - as you can see on your updated fiddle, it's not 100% height.

Comment: Use <span> instead of <div>, like in Pete answer.

Comment: I forgot add some css rules - .rel {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: Thanks @WaNgeL, Pete's solution helped. +1 for you help.