# How to stretch the div along the parent's tr height in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have some code like below. How to make it work in IE11 like in Chrome? I need stretch **div** along the parent's **tr** height.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative; width: 50px">
      <div style="height: 50px; background-color: #0C59CF"></div>
    </td>
    <td style="position: relative; width: 50px">
    <div style="position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     bottom: 0; 
     left: 0; 
     right: 0; background-color: #5cb85c">
    </div>
    </td>    
 </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sz64jzvr/12/

Comment: this code is for example and background color just illustrate a problem if you open this in IE11

Answer (score 0):

Check [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900433/absolute-positioning-inside-a-table-cell-in-ie/49322465#49322465) about a solution for this issue. Fully tested in all browsers.