# Flexbox's child is not getting the correct height in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Consider this snippet (which works in all major browsers):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

#header {
  background: yellow;
}

#content {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

    <div id="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div id="content">


      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <video controls>
      <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>


  </div>
```

In IE11 the `td` item's height is set to `0`, whereas in other browsers it gets the correct value.

Due to this, the video tag is also zeroed out, and it is not visible.

Is this a known issue in IE11? I know about some `min-height` issue (from https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but it does not seem to correlate.

How can I make this working in IE11 while preserving the support for the other browsers too?

Comment: I don't get why you have the `<video>` in a `<table>`? Can't you just put it in a `<div>` and avoid this issue altogether?

Comment: found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49322465/1446710

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting the `<video>` content in a `<div>` instead of a `<table>`. Additionally, there's no need to absolutely position it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

#header {
  background: yellow;
}

#content {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

#videoWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div id="content">

    <div id="videoWrapper">
      <video controls>
      <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the table.

Comment: @Daniel are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

You created a new stacking context with `td { position: relative }` and without specific height/width values IE thinks it has zero height/width.

Simply remove `td {}` and modify your `video {...}` as noted in the snippet (actually remove the stacking context) and you will see IE works as expected.

Apparently more modern browsers have solved this issue.

This will be hard to test through Stackoverflow as SO (oddly enough) no longer supports IE11...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

#header {
  background: yellow;
}

#content {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
/* *** REMOVE ***
td {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}*/

/* *** KEEP *** */
video { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <video controls>
                    <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

For your convenience I added a more extensive snippet showing a table with multiple columns and rows. Disabled `table width/height`, added `table border-collapse` and a demo `td {...}`, again without `position: relative`. Tested to work in IE11 (9,10 mode too).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>SO 60492668</title>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

#header {
  background: yellow;
}

#content {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
}

table {
/*  width : 100%; /* temporary disabled */
/*  height: 100%; /* temporary disabled */
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse; /* ADD */
}
/* *** REMOVE ***
td {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}*/

/* *** KEEP *** */
td    { border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3); padding: .5rem } /* DEMO */
video { width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 20rem }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>column 1</td>
                <td>column 2</td>
                <td>column 3</td>
                <td>
                <video controls>
                    <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video></td>
                <td>column 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>column 1</td>
                <td>column 2</td>
                <td>column 3</td>
                <td>
                <video controls>
                    <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video></td>
                <td>column 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>column 1</td>
                <td>column 2</td>
                <td>column 3</td>
                <td>
                <video controls>
                    <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video></td>
                <td>column 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>column 1</td>
                <td>column 2</td>
                <td>column 3</td>
                <td>
                <video controls>
                    <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video></td>
                <td>column 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the table. Solution is under the link I've posted as comment.

Comment: @Daniel, take a closer look, I did not remove the table, just the `position: relative`. Plus, the link you gave does not have an accepted (green box) answer. It may still be open to dispute....just FYI. Additionally, I did not change any of your html code

Comment: I've done that but that was caused another issue (video went off-screen). That's why I need both the table both  `td { position: relative; }`. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: Well, you must have done something with the code in the mean time: I copied the snippet code into a new html document, tested it with the latest versions of Chrome, Edge2020, Firefox AND IE11 (plus 8,9,10 mode. IE8 mode fails) on W10. They all work like a charm without the video going off screen.