# css absolute position inside table-cell: strange Firefox display

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

I have a simple horizontal menu with two levels. This menu stretches to 100% width of the wrapper. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpsgv/

If you run this fiddle in any browser except Firefox, it displays the following, as expected:

[image]

If you run this fiddle in Firefox, it displays the following:

[image]

Looking at the code, the second level lists are absolutely positioned inside the first level items (which have `display: relative` style). So, setting the `left: 10px` style to second level list should position it 10px from the left side of its relatively positioned ancestor. Similarly for `top: 30px`. But in Firefox, instead, it positions it on the left side and at the top of I don't know what, maybe the body?

My question is, **is there any solution to make it display correctly in Firefox, without changing the HTML**?

P.S. I use `display: table-cell` because the menu must be spread evenly along 100% container width.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without changing html - anyway.

`position:absolute` forces `display: block`, read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Solution: wrap your menu item content to other element:

```
<li> 
    <div class="menu-item-container">
        <a href="#">Item</a>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">First</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

And css for wrapper:

```
.menu-item-container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is not resolvable without changing HTML? According to CSS rules it should work, (and it is working, except for FF)

Comment: @camcam, position: absolute forces display: block, read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: The only element positioned absolutely is the second level list. So, being displayed as block, it should be positioned absolutely within the first level `<li>`. Instead, it is positioned absolutely within the body element.

Comment: @camcam, first level "li" displayed as "table-cell", not a "block"! This is obviously stated in your code. It is right that is placed relative to the body, read docs carefully please.

Comment: But the problem is not with first level `li`, it's with second level `ul`. The problem is, why FF doesn't see the right ancestor with relative positioning.

Comment: I think you are right, it's necessary to change the HTML. Here is [a helpful post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629326/position-relative-in-firefox/7629567#7629567). And a [citation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) from w3.org: _The effect of 'position:relative' on (...) table-cell (...) elements is undefined._ So, that's why my table cell `li` ancestor is simply not positioned relatively, so it's not the valid ancestor for absolutely positioned `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `left:10px;` use `left:auto;`

This is workaround, not the real solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should give the most upper `ul` a position relative too, otherwise it will indeed use the window itself (or the body for that matter) as the positioning offset.

check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/gpsgv/13/

**Edit**

After some intense debate (see comments below) it seems firefox is more strict in handling table-like blocks. I couldn't find a cross-browser solution for this one, except for adding a wrapper-div inside the list item holding the second level lists. When I create menu's like that I always use the floating technique. You'll have a little bit more work in terms of sizing the list items (as tables fill up space themselves). Basically you'd do it like this:

Html:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        First level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Second level 1</li>
            <li>Second level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>First level 2</li>
    <li>First level 3</li>
    <li>First level 4</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul.nav { 
    float: left; /* Needed as a kind of clearfix. Other clearfix techniques also possible */
}

/* be sure to add the > to prevent from second level li's to float */
ul.nav > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

ul.nav > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

And to create the same result as the OP wants, check out this fiddle (checked in chrome and FF, no IE, but should be good): http://jsfiddle.net/gpsgv/17/

Comment: All children items are aligned to the left side of first block

Comment: ehrm... my dear @maximkou, have you seen the fiddle? It works like a charm (I've checked it in chrome as well as firefox). If it doesn't, please tell me what you see and which browser you are using.

Comment: I'm check in Firefox 22.0, in Chrome all good, yes. OS Windows 7

Comment: so am I... and the other part of my question; what exactly do you see? as my firefox renders it exactly as the OP wants it...

Comment: I don't now. I see what I see.

Comment: I just saw an upload by someone (he deleted is comment), in firefox, with the right output. can you also send a screen maximkou? I really don't understand why you would see it differently _in exactly the same browser and version_ than I do...

Comment: @giorgio I also see the same as maximkou, see the screenshot here: http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/2553/3qjo.jpg (it was me but I thought it was from the wrong fiddle)

Comment: @camcam now I'm really confused... that looks exactly the same as the first example in your question... that is how it should be, isn't it?

Comment: The screenshot looks like a mix of the two examples. The vertical position is correct (as in first example) but the horizontal position is incorrect (as in second). So, it's partially correct. That's because they are all alligned to the left side of the same `ul`.