# Nesting Absolute Elements in Relative Elements Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html-table, css-position

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

Does Firefox ignore relative positioning on table cells?

I am trying to nest an absolute positioned element inside a relatively positioned table cell but Firefox is ignoring the relative positioning on the table cell and the absolutely positioned element is positioned according to the browser window.

HTML:

```
<table><tbody><tr><td><span></span></td></tr></tbody></table>​
```

CSS:

```
table{
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
}
td {
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    background:#333;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Here's an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbRUS/)** on jsfiddle.

The proper formatting of this would be to have the span be positioned approximately at the horizontal center of the result window, but Firefox would position it all the way to the right of the window. Any workaround for this while the element remains absolutely positioned and **no static numbers for the right/left/margin properties...** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

To your table...

```
table{
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbRUS/1/)

Comment: Ahh I see... but why wouldn't it work with my HTML? http://jsfiddle.net/ecBm9/

Comment: this is more like it. Why can't you use the natural flow of the table to keep the element where you want it? Why does it have to be absolute? Help me understand your thought process here.

Comment: You can have it positioned relative and it stays left of the text "I wish to receive occasional newsletter emails." That's what you're going for right? Or do you actually need it to stay on the right side of the screen?

Comment: The element must be positioned absolutely have a look at this in Webkit browser and you'll see what I accomplish by absolutely positioning the checkbox. http://jsfiddle.net/ecBm9/2/

Comment: I'm talking about the checkbox...

Comment: [This looks good](http://jsfiddle.net/ecBm9/4/) to me.

Comment: No, the checkbox is not being contained in the `<td>`

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing what you're seeing then. I have Firefox v10.0.2 for Windows XP. What version do you have? I've seen browsers react differently depending on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `position:relative` off the `td` and onto the `table`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the top of the span is placed at the middle of the table cell - I guess because the element has an absolute position and it is in a table cell.

You can set a negative top margin that equals half the size of the span element:

```
span {
    ...
    height:20px;
    margin-top: -10px; /* this one */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/JWP8N/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is true, Firefox does ignore it, as per the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position):

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is **undefined**.

One common solution is to put a division inside the cell with `display: relative` and then the absolute positioning will work inside that, but this is really up to how you are using the table. If you are using it for layout, I would suggest finding an alternate way of achieving the layout. If it's tabular data, would floats work for you instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, floats would not work... the element must be positioned absolutely