# Div in td and absolute positioning in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a situation which is similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axEGM/3/). In Firefox absolute positioning doesn't work correctly.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements?lq=1). Better way is make it by add additional div like on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axEGM/9/).

Answer (score 1):

add `position:relative` to table too:
http://jsfiddle.net/axEGM/4/

why are you mixing tables and divs?

Comment: Not at all http://jsfiddle.net/axEGM/8/ And I mix tables and divs becouse it is more comfortable for me.

Comment: looks to me as if Firefox just doesn't support positioning on table elements

Answer (score 0):

this could help:

> #col {
>       position: relative;
>       display:block; }

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked

```
div {

    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```