# Firefox vs Chrome: Background overlay is incorrectly sized with display:table-cell

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, overlay, css-tables

I have a block of HTML/CSS that behaves differently in Firefox (22.0) and Chrome (28.0.1500.71).  I'm trying to figure out why.  I have created a jsfiddle so that the resulting output can be easily observed.  http://jsfiddle.net/treejanitor/Q8zn4/3/

The source below is attempting to overlay a simple background color upon a table cell with a set of div elements nested under a div with `display: table`.  Only the table cell which is marked with the playbtn class should have the overlay.

It appears that the `table-cell` CSS is problematic to Firefox when determining box model dimensions.  For some reason, the `top/bottom/left/right` CSS attributes are incorrectly using the outermost block, the `tbl` class' `<div>`.  This doesn't seem to be an issue with Chrome, Safari, IE9+.

When I changed the CSS display value from `table-cell` to `inline-block`, I believe I got the behavior I desired but I did not pursue it much further; I need the `display: table-cell` in order to properly managed a more complex table display including spacing between the table cells evenly distributed.

Anyone have any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div class="tbl">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/240" />
            <div class="playbtn"></div>
        </div>
        <div>Description</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/240" />
            <div class="playbtn"></div>
        </div>
        <div>Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tbl {
    display: table;
}
.tbl > div {
    display: table-row;
}
.tbl > div > div {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.playbtn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: +1 well formated, easy to test etc.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements for some more details and possible solutions.

Comment: Hmm, seems similar to this issue - hopefully not duplicating it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571910/firefox-cant-handle-absolute-positioning-within-displaytable-cell?rq=1

Comment: @kalley - I have a definite lead from the link you suggested.  Wrapping the contents of the cell with a `div` having a `position:relative` is getting me very close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS 2.1 specification "[9.3.1 Choosing a positioning scheme: 'position' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position)" says:

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

So even if all other browsers use the value `relative` as "expected", Firefox is not wrong ignoring it.

**Edit**

I think wrapping the content into another `<div>` with `position: relative;` would be the easiest solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="relative">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/240" />
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

div.relative {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
}

div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/QQTUU/)

Comment: Yes, I guess I had a hunch that it was a gray area from the link I had posted above.  I'm mostly looking for a practical solution if there is one, irrespective of the spec.  Thanks for the quick reply to confirm my suspicions on the exact specification.

Comment: @treejanitor I've updated my answer with a solution using a wrapper - like in the answer kalley linked in his comment.

Comment: perfect!  I just came to same answer, using your line-height as my final tweak.  My fiddle of the original with the changes is here.  http://jsfiddle.net/treejanitor/Q8zn4/4/  I will mark this answer correct.

Comment: Pretty nice result. I'm glad I could throw in my two cents here and it helped in the end. :)

Comment: I had weird rendering issue in Chrome like color not updated... by removing the `position: relative` on td it fixed those unexpected behaviors