# FireFox: TH as offset parent for absolute positioned box?

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

I have run into a problem with position:relative on `th` elements in FireFox.
In Chrome and IE the `th` element is a valid offset parent for absolute positioned elements.

```
<div class="relative">
    <p>fill some spacing</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Hello?
                <div id="absolute">Is it me you're looking for</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.relative {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid green;
}

th {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#absolute {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntQqL/2/

In FireFox the `#absolute` element is positioned at the very top of the `.relative`, in Chrome and IE it is positioned at the top of the `th`, like I expected.

Is this a well-known difference, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has to do with the way the `display` and `position` properties are handled...

If you put a `display:block` on your `th`, [it will work](http://jsfiddle.net/ntQqL/4/).

Christiaan answer [also works](http://jsfiddle.net/ntQqL/5/).

But I guess the best way to fix this issue would be to [put a relative positionned div inside your th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements).

Comment: I tried the last approach and that works. If th's default display is table-cell, I guess display:block also works, but it's not really a block, more an inline-block...

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to work when you put position:relative on the `table` instead of the `th`. Maybe that could be used as a workaround in your situation?

Comment: Nope, because a second th will have some unknown offset to the right, which I also want to maintain...