# CSS animation issue with Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, webkit

I'm experiencing a browser incompatibility issue for Firefox, which I can't seem to fix. This works fine in modern IE and Chrome, but you'll see that when you hover over a box that its contents show up at the very top for every one.

Here's the temporary location of the site, under construction: http://mastermobilemarketing.ca/campaigns/roybox/index.html

I use jQuery to handle the things that CSS can't do (or I just don't know how to), so there's a bit of a combination at play. Because this is clearly using CSS3, I know i'll have to dumb down the site for older browsers etc, but I at least want to get this working first.

Your assistance and general critiques (I don't mind, feel free to rip me apart, I'm still a bit of a novice) are highly appreciated.

Cheers - - Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: relative`  on `<td>` is invalid in Firefox. [The first answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements) is the solution.