# Positioning a div within a div

Tags: html, css

I have the following div table:

```
<div style="display:table">
  <div style="display:table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell">
      <div id="innerDiv"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside the cell is a div with the id "innerDiv". Is there a way to position this div such that its top/left corner is located anywhere within the cell? I tried all the css position values but none work.

Comment: You can't use `positioning` inside a `table cell` as freely as you can inside a `relative`ly positioned `block` element.

Comment: Please share a JSFiddle. I think it should become a standard on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not supposed to give the same element `table-cell display` and `relative position`. It's not supported equally between modern browsers (try this in FF).

If it's the only way you can do things on your specific case, add a relatively positioned wrapper div inside the cell.

For example:

```
<div style="display:table">
  <div style="display:table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell">
      <div class="relativeDiv">
          <div id="innerDiv"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.relativeDiv
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* You may need some negative margin 
       if there's a padding on the table cell */
    position: relative;
}

#innerDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    /* You're now free to set the top and left attributes freely */
}
```

For further reading:

- http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/
- [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use position property in outer div explicitly（such as: relative,fiexd,absolute)

```
div {
  position: relative;
};

#innerDiv {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
}
```