# Firefox doesn't center with table:middle;

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

The caption is properly centered in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox: [link to my site](http://felipes.se/ebap.se/test.html)

http://wisercoder.com/firefox-displaytable-cell-and-absolute-positioning/ states:

> "Firefox doesn’t support a combination of display:table-cell and
>   position:relative"

Does that have anything to do with the problem? Is there a Firefox fix for centering the caption?

The site is responsive so the `table:middle;` solution is great because you don't have to set a height.

Comment: Try this to change: `.front-page-caption { display: table; }` to `.front-page-caption { display: block; }` (On css: app.css:7638)

Comment: Sorry, it's neither working in Firefox nor Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Ok... Try this on app.css:7655 `top:40%` and `margin: 0 auto` ... by the way.. the first comment make the image responsive in FF

Comment: This isn't an option because it's a respovsive site and the caption gets out of center if I use top:40%

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is to wrap the div which has display:table-cell with another div and make him position relative instead of the original one. helped me.

Found the original question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)