# Creating a line behind elements with CSS :before

Tags: css

It is possible to create a line (*the gray line below*) with `:before` that appers **behind** elements from it's parent div?

**What I have: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/1/**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new parent element (`div`) to attach a class to. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/6/

```css
.gray-bar {
  position: relative;
}

.gray-bar::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  left: 33px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.row.fluid {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray-bar">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row fixed"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/AKmmXE4.gif" /></div>
    <div class="row fluid">Hello, I'm Mickey!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <div class="row fixed"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/f6948mH.gif" /></div>
    <div class="row fluid">I'm Goofy!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <div class="row fixed"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Dm2vlrA.gif" /></div>
    <div class="row fluid">I'm Donald Duck!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <div class="row fixed"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vRggi12.gif" /></div>
    <div class="row fluid">Whoof!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not(:last-child)` to exclude the last `.table` element from the selection. From there, just add an absolutely positioned `:after` pseudo element to the `.row.fixed` element - it should be relative to the parent. As for positioning, use `left:50%` and `margin-left:-3px` (half the width).

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgxdB/)

```
.table:not(:last-child) .row.fixed:after {
    content:'';
    width: 6px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -3px;
    top: 100%;
}
```

As [Nico O points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514874/creating-a-line-behind-elements-with-css-before/22515019#comment34257726_22515019), there is a bug in FF with `relative`/`absolutely` positioned table element. Here is [one possible](http://jsfiddle.net/RSs85/) workaround using the CSS from above.

Comment: Nice, really clean and repsonsive. But seems to be broken in Firefox. (Table `position: relative;` bug)

Comment: @NicoO 1+ Since yours works in FF.. Thanks for pointing that out. I've experienced that bug in FF before but I'm not sure how I fixed it. Any ideas?

Comment: I like your solution way better. But this bug is really annoying ... I don't think there is a workaround for this use case... Hopefully someone prove me wrong

Comment: @NicoO It's an ugly solution [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/RSs85/) .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements

Answer (score 1):

a wrapper and a background works fine too: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/60/

```
<div class="lined">
<!-- here your divs -->
</div>
```

gradient version :

```
.lined {
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 32px, #DADADA 32px, #DADADA 38px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 38px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    /* gradient can be a few pix gray image repeated for older brower*/

}
img {
    vertical-align:top;/* to avoid gap underneath*/
}
```

image version http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/63/ :

```
.lined {
    background:url(http://dummyimage.com/6x2/dadada/dadada) repeat-y  32px
}
img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**### DEMO**

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
.table{
    position: relative;
}

.table:before{
    content: "";
    height: 40px;
    border-left: 5px solid #ddd;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 32px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.table:first-child::before{
    border-left: none;
}
```

**Note:** `position: relative`; on `.table` and also `position: absolute;` and `z-index: -1;` on `:before` guarantee that the pseudo element created by `:before` will not overlap the actual elements.

Comment: :last-child is not supported in IE8

Comment: @Sigma Correct, updated the answer to be compatible with IE8, too.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/51/). Fully responsive No matter how many icons and the data has added. the layout will not be affected.

```
div.table:last-child:before{border:0;} /*this will remove the border from the last child*/

div.table:before{
position:absolute;
content: " ";
left:42px;
height:22%;
border-left:6px solid #D3D3D3;
 z-index:-1; /*this negative value required to put the line behind the image*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/61/
http://jsfiddle.net/2Qn4Y/61/show
No need for extra containers.

```
.table {
    position: relative;
}
.table:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DADADA;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    width: 4px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.table:first-child:after {
   content: "";
   display: none;
}
```