# pseudo-elements and <ul> display: table

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

In Firefox (27.0.1) I can't position `:after` relative to the `<li>` it pertains to, if the `<li>` is `display: table-cell;`

#### http://jsfiddle.net/6WHN6/

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

li:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: 33.3%;
}

li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Is there a way to style a psuedo-element on an `<li>` relative to that `<li>` in Firefox, if that li is `display: table-cell;`, and if not, why?

In the fiddle, you can see that the pseudo-elements have a left-margin which is 33.3% the width of the document.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm trying to get an explanation or solution for this difference in rendering between browsers. Not just trying to make a table with borders, I think the fiddle shows problem well. --Updated question.

Comment: Firefox has a bug with `position:relative;` `<table>` elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position)

> The **effect of 'position:relative'** on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, **table-cell**, and table-caption elements **is undefined**.

As `position: absolute` will be computed from closest parent with `position: relative` (or root body), it ignores "table-cell w/ position: relative" parent and will compute from other ancestral.