# Bug in Firefox? Table being rendered differently in Chrome/IE & Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Following JS Fieddle shows expected output on IE & Chrome, But in Firefox, it's completely different.

Whats problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kQXkt/7/

```
table {
    width:90%;
}
td {
    width:30%;
    position:relative;
}
td .dummy{
    margin-top:100%;
}
td .content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:gold;
}


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <div class="content">1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

Comment: @CBroe may be this is same issue, but questions is not duplicate for sure.