# Firefox :before position absolute incorrect

Tags: css, firefox, css-position, pseudo-element

### [[Duplicate of Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

I have an unordered list with vertical rules between the list-items:

**HTML**

```html
<ul class="list-inner-border">
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
.list-inner-border {
    height: 100px;
}

.list-inner-border li {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative; // not having this usually causes the misbehaviour
    width: 1%;
}
.list-inner-border li + li:before {
    background-color: red;
    content: '';
    height: 80%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}

span {
    background-color: gray;
    display: block;
    height:90px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypXZZ/1/)

The above works in all browsers except Firefox, which behaves as if the container of position:absolute does not have positioning of its own (common oversight with position:absolute):

Chrome:

[image: List inner border working in Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: List inner border not working in Firefox]

In Firefox, all the `:before`s have jumped outside their container and stacked vertically along the edge of the root element.

Comment: Why the link?  Don't you have enough rep to vote to close?  Though if you can't, I understand there.  I have never voted to close my own question, so I don't know if its any different.

Comment: I do have enough rep ([Privilege: Close questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)). I voted to close rather than deleting in case someone experiences a similar issue. The root problem was Firefox ignoring positioning of table.

Comment: .. But, you didn't vote to close.  I'm the only one that has.  Unless there's something I'm missing, all you did was edit your question to include a link to a possible duplicate at the top.

Comment: Oh whoops. I don't know what happened. I added the link to the question for the time before it gets enough votes to close. I guess I forgot to add my own vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Elements with `position: absolute;` are actually meant to refer to the next parent with `position:absolute;`.</s> jacob proved me wrong here.

If you assign 0 to `left` or `top`, they align to the root element. Leave those away and the rules' positions are correct in firefox.

Because all your percentage based values are differently calculated, you might need absolute values there. You could also make a fallback for firefox: [Targeting only Firefox with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)

Sorry I haven't found anything better

Comment: "Elements with position: absolute; are actually meant to refer to the next parent with position:absolute;" That is not correct. They refer to the closest ancestor with a position that is not `static`.

Comment: Removing `left: 0` and `top: 0` solved it: http://jsfiddle.net/ypXZZ/14/ Thanks!

Comment: Strangely, I also needed to set `position: relative` to the `ul` to contain the height.