# Position relative issue at specific browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I'm facing a strange problem. I've put [this sortable table](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) at my webpage. I've modified css and put `position: relative;` at the cell of table header. [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/WEB38/1/). You'll look there is a border at each header cell(if you open the page by chrome browser). But, that border can't be seen at firefox and internet explorer. Only from chrome, that border can be shown!

By chrome browser:

[image]

By firefox and internet explorer:

[image]

I've noticed that if I remove the `position: relative;` from css:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
}
```

that border can be shown from every browser!! But, I need that `position: relative` for some reasons. So, what's the reason for disappearing that border from firefox and ie? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please note that Firefox doesn't support positioning of table elements (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `border-collapse` on the tr and add `border-spacing:0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

By default `border-collapse: separate;` is applied for table tag, but in your case `border-collapse: collapse;` is creating problems. Try removing it from `table.tablesorter` css class.
here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEB38/10/)