# How to position elements inside a TD or TH without getting a warning in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, warnings, css-position

I'm using an absolutely positioned element in a table header cell. To do this, the TH has to be positioned itself, to make it the child element's offsetParent (in my case, using `position:relative`). Unfortunately, it appears that current Firefox versions will issue a warning any time a TD or TR is given a position other than static.

With the following minimal table HTML

```
<table>
<tr><th>head</th></tr>
<tr><td>cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

and the following minimal CSS rules

```
th { position: relative }  // either of these is enough
td { position: relative }  // to trigger the warning
table { border-collapse: collapse }
```

this warning appears in the console for Firefox 30 and 32:

> *Relative positioning of table rows and row groups is now supported. This site may need to be updated because it may depend on this feature
>   having no effect.*

(the warning does not appear when the table borders are kept separate)

The source of this message is [Firefox's table layout code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mozilla/firefox/layout/tables/nsTableFrame.cpp#269):

```
/* static */ void
nsTableFrame::RegisterPositionedTablePart(nsIFrame* aFrame)
{
  // Supporting relative positioning for table parts other than table cells has
  // the potential to break sites that apply 'position: relative' to those
  // parts, expecting nothing to happen. We warn at the console to make tracking
  // down the issue easy.
```

So it seems we get this warning even if we're doing nothing wrong at all, because other sites may rely on the `position` rule doing "nothing". Is there a way to get rid of this annoying warning? It's basically telling me: Warning, what you're doing actually works!

Comment: Even if you could get rid of the warning message, it doesn't mean that it would get `position: relative` to work on table cells. According to CSS Level 2 spec the effect of `position: relative` on table-cell,... is *undefined*.

Comment: @HashemQolami True, but the warning itself and the source comment say that positioning table parts is now supported in FF. The source comment also suggests that only positioning "table parts _other than_ table cells" could lead to breakage, and I'm not doing that.

Comment: your question seems to be answered in the following thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same warning and resolved it by applying positioning to a div inside the th or td rather than directly to the td or th. Not sure why it cares but now I don't need to see it anymore.

```
td div{position:relative;}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `td > div`, otherwise you'll select other descendant `<div>` elements too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<table>
<tr><th><span class="pos1">head</span></th></tr>
<tr><td><span class="pos2">cell</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.pos1{
position:absolute;
top:25px /* example*/
}

.pos2{
position:absolute;
top:10px /* example*/
}
```

Comment: Not really. In your example, the SPAN elements would be positioned relative to the BODY, which is not what I need.

Comment: Even if you add a relative position to th and td?

Comment: Yes, but then I get the warning again :) Anyway, this appears to be a bug in Firefox, and a patch has already been committed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1081683