# How can I make table column widths fixed?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with two columns, first column 65%, second 35%. It perfectly fits to 100% of screen, if first column has enough text in it to fill that 65%, but if it is empty (or small amount of text) - then first column shrinks and second expands.

How can I make first column ALWAYS 65% of screen, with or without text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654481/lock-table-cells-to-their-default-size-regardless-of-content - does table-layout:fixed help here?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<table class="fixed_width">
    <col width="65%" />
    <col width="35%" />
    <tr>
        <td>your data</td>
        <td>your data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
table.fixed_width { table-layout:fixed; }
table.fixed_width td { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 65%;">
            first column
        </td>
        <td style="width: 35%;">
            second column
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first column will always stay 65% unless, you put something inside that is larger then 65% (a large picture for example)

Comment: Thanks. But this is not working. I made first <table width=100%> and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    empty-cells: show;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/empty-cells

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout

@kalpesh's recommendation for `<colgroup>` is a good one too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/colgroup

Comment: Can you explain what they do?

Comment: @MyStream I updated my answer with references and a comment on a subsequent answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this css :

```
.table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .td1 {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 65%;
    }

    .td2{border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 35%;
    }
```

and

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td class="td1">data</td>
        <td class="td2">data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```