# force html table to fit in predetermined size (constant width, height) div regardless of content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have been trying to force a table to fit in a printable page, regardless of how many items exist and am having trouble doing so. the only way i have found is to change font size but that isn't exactly automatic.

i have found a lot of answers setting with to a specific width, but the vertical side is difficult. I dont want any overflow to occur and resize the text to show all content in that box.

[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654481/lock-table-cells-to-their-default-size-regardless-of-content)

i have been using a setting of 300px wide and 777px tall

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
table
{
 max-height: 300px;
 max-width: 700px;
}
table, table * {white-space: nowrap;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in css table-layout:fixed. For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp